# TypeError method object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to set the trimester of this [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9ajy7szesji6wp/accidentalidad2017.csv?dl=0) with pandas to start working. I already tried the date_range and others with dates but it doesn't work because there are many (many) rows with the same index. So I'm trying with the .loc but if I use **and** I get an ambiguous error, so I don't know what to do.

Heeeeelp

I have this code

```
    import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib as pld

#COMENZAR 
header_list = ['OBJECTID','X','Y','RADICADO','FECHA','HORA','DIA','PERIODO','CLASE','DIRECCION','DIRECCION_ENC','CBML','TIPO_GEOCOD','GRAVEDAD','BARRIO','COMUNA','DISENO']

data = pd.read_csv('Datasets/accidentalidad2017.csv', engine='python', sep=',', header=1, names=header_list)


column=['FECHA','HORA','DIA','CLASE','GRAVEDAD','BARRIO']
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=column)
df.set_index('FECHA',inplace=True) #convertir la columna FECHA en el index



# Filtro por fecha

dt = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

start='2017-1'
end='2017-3'
fecha= df.any[(dt >=start) | (dt <=end)]
print(fecha)
```

Comment: Please see here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for a guide on asking questions. Others should be able to recreate your problem easily. And please print out your stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

`TypeError method object is not subscriptable` means that you tried to call a function using `[]` instead of `()`

There is a difference between `print("banana")` and `print["banana"]`